# MySQL "show create table" result without "\n" separator

Tags: mysql

In MySQL Workbench or in (PHP/JS/... programming tools) if we use SQL statement:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table1;
```

We get something like this:

*'table1', 'CREATE TABLE `table1` (\n  `ID` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `YM` mediumint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,\n* ...

Interestingly, the same resulting CREATE statement cannot be re-used to re-create a table, because it contains the "\n" separators. Programmatically this can be treated easily, but is there an option in MySQL directly that can be added to the SQL statement to instruct MySQL to suppress the output of the "\n" separators?

Comment: Why do you say it cannot be reused to recreate the table? It should be - by definition.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has no options for anything.

The format for the command is

> SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name

[see manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)